# DirectAdmin Apache/Nginx Reverse Proxy Custom Subdomain Config

Tags: linux, nginx, apache-2.4

I have a particular application on a subdomain that needs a custom Nginx configuration to work. I am using DirectAdmin control panel to make per-domain customisations. However, I am getting confused with the config and the format it needs to be in for it to work.
Setup is Apache server with Nginx reverse proxy

Any advice on how to customise this and add it to DirectAdmin would be much appreciated.

Config

````
        server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

        root /path/to/your/website.com/;
        index index.html index.php;

        # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
        
        location /backups {
                deny all;
                return 404;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
}```
````